# VC++ hangs and freezes computer upon completion of compilation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, windows-forms-designer

When the compiling of a project is complete (or at least when it says it does), I receive no window, no error message, or anything; VC++ freezes up and my computer basically stops responding altogether.

After about five minutes, Task Manager finally pops up and I'm able to close the program. Upon doing that, I see this:
[image]

I'm going to take a *wild* guess here and say something is wrong with the image above. On a side note, the process' (`MSBuild.exe`) don't (seem) to open all at once, but that may only seem that way because the computer becomes frozen multiple times until I shutdown vc++.

Is this a known issue and if so what should I do so I can compile programs without this issue once again?

**Additional Information**:

- Windows 7
- Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 xpress
- **Project Type(s):** I've tried on "Windows Form Application" project and "Win32 Project", both produce the same results.
- Compiling projects in VB works as it should. (in case this helps at all)

Comment: This is environmental.  Kill Avast first.  Etcetera.

Comment: @HansPassant: Hmm, I didn't even think that would of been the issue. Turning off Avast seemed to work. Add it as an actual answer and I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Hans Passant, disabling *avast!* solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did any error pop up during installation?

The standard thing to do (that almost always helps) is rebooting, reinstalling, (rebooting,) and trying again. Chances are absolutely nobody knows what's going wrong (even MS).

Comment: I don't believe there was any error, and I have tried rebooting and re-installing.

Comment: Try building your project from the commandline. Open a visual studio command prompt, `cd` to your project's directory, and call MSBuild yourself. Does that cause the same problem?

Comment: @rubenvb: (absolute beginner here) How would I call MSBuild? I don't see it in the project directory at all.

Comment: @Shaz: By using the Visual Studio command prompt (available from the Visual Studio start menu) you can just do `MSBuild.exe your_project.sln` after `cd`ing to the project directory. It is the Visual studio build tool that is run by the IDE when you click "build".

Comment: @rubenvb: It worked without any errors or warnings (but nothing happened afterwards)

Comment: Well you've got me stumped and my google-fu isn't helping either. Perhaps try the Microsoft forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/category/vsexpress